I have a column in my pandas dataframe that contains cities I want to create aonther column that returns the respetive country to this city
i have a column in my dataframe where it contains different cities from all over the world i want to create a new column based on this column which returns the country of each city in pandas dataframe how can i do that ?
I tried the opencage geo coding with python but it did not solve my problem
